# intuitive explanation of Primal-Dual algorithms

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming, duality-theorems

I've recently heard of Primal-Dual algorithms and I was wondering if someone could give me an intuitive explanation of it. I searched online, but did not find an intuitive explanation. I'd be glad if you could point me to sources that give an overview. I am just trying to get a sense in general.

Thank you in advance

EDIT : I am mainly interested in primal dual algorithms to solve linearly constrained optimization problems with a convex objective function.

Comment: The term "primal-dual algorithm" is pretty broad. I believe this includes any algorithm that simultaneously solves for both the primal optimal variables and the dual optimal variables. Can you say a little more about what kind of algorithm you're thinking of?

Comment: I just updated my post, thanks.

Comment: The following may be helpful   www.cs.ubc.ca/~pcarbo/lp.pdf‎